# Scipy, tf-idf and cosine similarity

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, trigonometry, tf-idf

I'm trying to cluster some documents according to a tf-idf matrix using python.

First I follow the wikipedia definition of the formula, using normalised tf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf

Feat_vectors starts as a two dimensional numpy array, with the rows representing documents and the columns representing terms, the values in each cell being the number of occurrences of each term in each document.

```
import numpy as np

feat_vectors /= np.max(feat_vectors,axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
idf = len(feat_vectors) / (feat_vectors != 0).sum(0)
idf = np.log(idf)
feat_vectors *= idf
```

I then cluster these vectors using scipy:

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

clusters = hierarchy.linkage(feat_vectors,method='complete',metric='cosine')
flat_clusters = hierarchy.fcluster(clusters, 0.8,'inconsistent')
```

However, on that last line it throws an error:

```
ValueError: Linkage 'Z' contains negative distances.
```

Cosine similarity goes from -1 to 1. However, the wikipedia page for cosine similarity states http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity :

> In the case of information retrieval, the cosine similarity of two documents will range >from 0 to 1, since the term frequencies (tf-idf weights) cannot be negative.

So if I am getting a negative similarity, it seems that I am making some error in calculating tf-idf. Any ideas what my mistake is?

Comment: Looks like your `feat_vectors` has negative values. Either before multiplying by `idf`, or idf has values lower than 1 before you take `np.log`.

Comment: The minimum value in the matrix is zero. It's just that the result of the cosine similarity is <0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is in the following line:

```
idf = len(feat_vectors) / (feat_vectors != 0).sum(0)
```

since your logical vector is going to be converted to an int in the sum, and len is an int, you're losing precision. Replacing with:

```
idf = float(len(feat_vectors)) / (feat_vectors != 0).sum(0)
```

worked for me (i.e. produced what I was expecting with dummy data). Everything else looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but seem to have stumbled into this problem myself recently.
In fact, I even used the TfidfVectorizer (from sklearn.feature_extraction.text) to  generate the TFIDF matrix, once my own functions gave this error. This did not help either.

It appears that the cosine metric being used for similarity induces negative values. I tried euclidean in place and it worked instantly.
Here is a link to a more detailed answer for the same which I found - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590194/3228300

Hope this helps.